# Ambari on Docker Cloudera repo file needs user and password now

Tags: wget, cloudera, ambari

I had an script that automatically would create an Ambari cluster using docker. In the file:
https://github.com/ortizfabio/caochong/blob/master/from-ambari/Dockerfile
There is a line to download Ambari. This used to work until Cloudera took over. I am trying to change the command that download Ambari from:

```
RUN wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.0.0/ambari.repo
```

to:

```
RUN wget --http-user=email_logon --http-password=my_password  -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo https://archive.cloudera.com/p/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.7.5.0/ambari.repo
```

However I get error:

```
Connecting to archive.cloudera.com (archive.cloudera.com)|151.101.208.167|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authentication required
Authentication selected: Basic realm=Secured
Connecting to archive.cloudera.com (archive.cloudera.com)|151.101.208.167|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Authentication failed
2020-05-29 00:35:40 ERROR 403: Authentication failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Fabio  Your options are:

1. Contact Cloudera, become a customer, and get an Enterprise License with user and password authorized to access their paywalled versions
2. Use the last free version 2.7.4
3. Build From Source

If you are looking to use HDP,  I suggest #2 as the easiest option:

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.7.4.0/ambari.repo
```

If you truly want 2.7.5 you can build from source yourself, or I have created some RPMS you can use without HDP:

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/mosga.repo https://makeopensourcegreatagain.com/rpms/mosga.repo
yum install ambari-server ambari-agent -y
ambari-server setup -s
```

I am currently still working on the next part where my RPMS will install DDP (Demo Data Platform) with common HDP Components and some other Third Party Components we use here at DFHz.

Comment: How do you do using Ambari 2.7.5  don't need HDP. I compile Ambari 2.7.5 by myself, but when I configure the cluster, it still asks me to provide HDP files.

Comment: @SmithCruise ambari and HDP are still very coupled together.  Even when you build ambari from source, HDP still exists in /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/.   From the install wizard you have to provide a stack structure, telling ambari which versions to use.   The HDP version of ambari from Hortonworks or Cloudera repos already includes HDP Stack. An HDF Management pack installs HDF stack....    as I type this I am working on building a custom stack...

Comment: Ha, I am your firm supporter! What platform did your software pass on? Let me have a test.

Comment: centos7/redhat7 (yum install) https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/dfhz_ddp_mpack

Comment: The second option doesn't work with me, I get this error: The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘makeopensourcegreatagain.com’

Comment: Thanks kate, the cert is sorted now.   Highly recommend that you DO NOT use 3 year old HDP, this product is end of life.   Move to CDP Private Cloud or CDP Public Cloud.